# Retrofit: Get original response body when request fails

Tags: android, retrofit, robospice

I am using Retrofit (1.6.1) with Robospice (1.4.14) to get data from some services (response should be in JSON).

In some cases, I might receive a HTML error page instead of a JSON response. The server returns a 200 status code, and I can not change that. In such cases, RoboSpice will call the `onRequestFailure(SpiceException)` method.

There, I am able to get the original `RetrofitError` excpetion, but the body is `null`.  This is how I get it:

```java
if (spiceException.getCause() instanceof RetrofitError) {
    RetrofitError error = (RetrofitError) spiceException.getCause();
    error.getBody(); // returns null
}
```

After investigating the source code of Retrofit, I found out that the body is replaced with `null` if the conversion fails (which is the case here, as Retrofit expect JSON and receives HTML).

The following line in `RestAdapter` is the source of my issue:

```java
response = Utils.replaceResponseBody(response, null);
```

Is there a way to not set the body to `null`? In an other SO question, I found that if the server returns 4xx, the body is kept, but I can not change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably create a retrofitted method that will just return a `retrofit.client.Response` and manually call conversion on it if the response body is in the necessary format.

Your Retrofit interface:

```
...
@GET("/foo/bar")
Response fooBarMethod(Object foo, Object bar);
...
```

Your RoboSpice request:

```
...
@Override
public final FooBar loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    Response r = getService().fooBarMethod(foo, bar);
    if (isBodyInHtmlFormat()) {
        // cool stuff
        throw new ResponseIsHtmlException();
    } else {
        // it is wise to make sure that it is 
        // exactly the same converter you are passing to
        // your RetrofitSpiceService
        Converter converter = createGsonConverter();
        return (FooBar) converter.fromBody(response.getBody(), FooBar.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Has to do some refactoring to include this, but it works nicely. Thanks!